# Regex Expression evaluation

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as follows: entries(a,b,c,d,e)

I would like to split the following into an array in java as

```
 arr[0]= 'a'
 arr[1]= 'b'
 arr[2]= 'c'
 arr[3]= 'd'
 arr[4]= 'e'
```

Anyone have any idea on the regex to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything or searched before asking this?

Comment: Why a regex when there is a command to "split' ((cough)blatant hint(cough))?

Comment: Because the split command takes a regex as an argument? :-) Even if it will contain only one character in this case.

Comment: I have but I am not familiar with regex expressions other than the very basic

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/2764279)

Comment: @Jongware `String#split()` also uses regex. That's why we see questions like "`split(".")` doesn't work"

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] arr = "entries(a,b,c,d,e)".split("\\(|\\)")[1].split(",");
```

Explanation: You have the string "entries(a,b,c,d,e)" and first want to get to the "a,b,c,d,e" part. I use split here and define that I want to split by "(" or ")". Gives me the array

```
a[0] = "entries"
a[1] = "a,b,c,d,e"
```

Take the second entry and split it by ",", hence `[1].split(",")` at the end.

Comment: thank you! Can you explain your logic? I do not understand what you did after .split("\\(|\\)")